# Type erasure: do we risk non-reversibly losing access to kept-alive data of the instance of the erased type, when erasing the type information?

Tags: swift, type-erasure

Consider the following common simple type erasure scheme

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar
    func bar() -> Bar
}

struct AnyFoo<Bar>: Foo {
    private let _bar: () -> Bar

    init<F: Foo>(_ foo: F) where F.Bar == Bar {
        _bar = foo.bar
            /* stores a reference to foo.bar,
               so foo kept alive by ARC? */
    }

    func bar() -> Bar {
        return _bar()
    }
}
```

Assume the initializer argument `foo` above is (intended to be) a temporary instance of a "large" type, from which we're only interested to slice out the information blueprinted by `Foo` (i.e., the `bar()` method).

```
struct Huge { /* ... */ }

struct Foobar: Foo {
    internal func bar() -> String {
        return "foo"
    }
    let lotsOfData: Huge = Huge()
}

func getAnyFooStr() -> AnyFoo<String> {
    let foobar = Foobar()
    return AnyFoo(foobar)
}

let anyStrFoo = getAnyFooStr()
    /* we can now access anyStrFoo.bar() (-> "foo") from our
       erased type, but do lotsOfData of the underlying seemingly
       temporary Foobar() instance still "live", unreachable? */
```

- **Q:** Will we still keep the remaining content of `foo` alive and unreachable in memory due to the fact that closures are reference types? And if so, I assume we would never be able to reclaim access to this lost-but-alive content?

*(I tried the above with `Foobar` as a class, monitoring the (lack of a) `deinit` call, but I've confused myself so much the last hour that I need some non-self verification for this, especially for the case when `Foobar` is a value type)*

---

Xcode 8.0 / Swift 3.

Comment: `Foobar` should be released as soon as `anyStrFoo` goes out of scope. You can verify that by replacing `Huge` by a class with a deinit method.

Comment: @MartinR but as long as the `AnyFoo` instance is in scope, the `Foobar` instance is non-released (with non-reachable data)? Ninja-edit: also, as you say, when `anyStrFoo` goes out of scope the `Foobar` instance (and in so the `Huge` member instance of it) is released, thanks.

Comment: I don't see the real problem here. The same would happen if you assign `let fb = Foobar().bar` which is the `bar` method bound to an instance (don't know if that is the correct term). It keeps the value alive as long as `fb` is alive. The closure might need the instance, so what else should happen?

Comment: @MartinR ah of course, I ran into my query while already working with type erasure and totally overcomplicated things. Clearly an instance method might need access to the underlying instance, even if the type is "erased" in the eyes of the developer (semantics based confusion from my side). Thanks! (So answer to this Q is _"yes, and this has nothing in particular to do with type erasure"_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it has nothing to do with type erasure :)
The closure `Foobar().bar` keeps the instance that it is bound to
(with all its properties) alive as long as the closure is alive.

Here is a simplified example:

```
class Huge {
    deinit { print("deinit Huge") }
}

struct Foobar {
    internal func bar() -> String {
        return "foo"
    }
    let lotsOfData: Huge = Huge()
}

do {
    let fb  = Foobar().bar // the type of `fb` is `() -> String`
    print("still alive ...")
}
print("... out of scope now")
```

Output:

```
still alive ...
deinit Huge
... out of scope now
```